# Fire and forget with GetResponseAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

Am trying to achieve a fire and forget situation with HttpWebRequest GetResponseAsync without setting up an await on it. Are there any potential dangers am over looking?

Comment: Who will observe the exception, if any?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many "potential dangers" around using fire-and-forget on ASP.NET.

In the most general case, you can only use fire-and-forget if you *don't care whether the code actually gets executed or not*. I have [more details on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) and [so does Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/).

Answer (score 0):

One possible danger would be ASP.NET shuts the server's thread pool down , your GetResponseAsync is going to get killed and won't start itself up again even after the server wakes up